# Embedded JRuby access to classes available to ScriptEngine

Tags: jruby

I am adding JRuby support to a system that already has Jython support.

Something appears to be different between the access Jython has to the parent classloader environment and what JRuby has.  Jython seems to have full access to any classes the ScriptEngine who invokes the python script, JRuby seems to only have access to java.* items.

The following Jython code works and creates a log entry:

```
from org.slf4j import LoggerFactory

def scriptLoaded(id):
  LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.openhab.core.automation.examples").info("Hello world!")
```

The following jruby code does results in an error:

```
def scriptLoaded(id)
  org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.openhab.core.automation.examples").info("Hello Ruby")
end
```

Error:

```
NameError: missing class name (`org.slf4j.LoggerFactory')
  method_missing at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaPackage.java:252
    scriptLoaded at <script>:35
```

This is running within the same system.

Is there a method for JRuby to search its parent classloader?

Comment: any chance you would share the setup, is it a bare-bone javax.script engine boot?
where is jruby.jar located on the class-path?